# FFMpeg concat streams

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, h.264, concatenation

I am trying to receive two H264 UDP streams from two cameras, and save them to one file (so they are always synchronized). I tried a lot of things, but it always says that there is no video on the second stream (although I can watch it).

```
ffmpeg -probesize 20M -analyzeduration 20M -i udp://@127.0.0.1:1234 -probesize 20M -analyzeduration 20M -i udp://@127.0.0.1:1235 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=15,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [1:v]fps=15,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 [v0] [v1]" -map "[v0]" -map "[v1]" -threads 0 -y kk.ts
```

Is it possible to apply the concat to real time streams, so we have a video with two programs as a result?

Comment: sorry, I asked here because after a google search I saw several other (answered) posts about ffmpeg.

Comment: If SO is the right place for this question can be discussed (maybe) - but as ffmpeg is a tag on SO down-voting is not the right attitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not allowed to reply i'll post this.

Gerfried, I'll agree that downvoting only is used to promote your self... so stop doing that kind of actions, just because a new user made a mistake and/or the board setup do not allow one to do a action.

To do as suggested in the original question, I'll suggest you try to use

ffmpeg -i concat(file1,file2)

http://reck.dk/ffmpeg-combine-or-merge-several-video-into-one-video-concatenating-media-files/